# How to tell if my home is encrypted or not?

Tags: login, encryption, home-directory

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 a while ago and can not remember whether I chose to have my home folder encrypted or not.

How can I find out easily whether my own home on my machine is encrypted (while I am logged in)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While logged in, run `mount` (by itself, no arguments). If you see something about ecryptfs, your HOME is encrypted.

Comment: Works well. For me, the relevant line was the last in the output of quite a few.